# Optimizing by using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Lets say I have the following list:

```
StringLists = ['1,8,0,9','4,5,2,2','4,6,7,2','4,2,8,9']
```

And I want to generate the following result:

```
FinalList = [[1,8,0,9],[4,5,2,2],[4,6,7,2],[4,2,8,9]]
```

I am using the following code:

```
TempList = [d.split(',') for d in StringLists]
FinalList = list()
for alist in TempList:
    FinalList.append([int(s) for s in alist])
```

The result is ok, but i was wondering if there is something more elegant. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
FinalList = [list(map(int, d.split(','))) for d in StringLists]
```

Note that if you are using Python 2, you do not have to cast the result:

```
FinalList = [map(int, d.split(',')) for d in StringLists]
```

Comment: Map returns a list, you don't need to convert its output to list again.

Comment: @Riyaz In Python 3, `map()` does not return a list but a map object.

Comment: @Riyaz: in Python 3 `map()` returns an iterable, not a list. In that case, I usually prefer a nested list comprehension: `[[int(i) for i in d.split(',')] for d in StringLists]`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it

```
>>> [[int(s) for s in string.split(',')] for string in StringLists]
[[1, 8, 0, 9], [4, 5, 2, 2], [4, 6, 7, 2], [4, 2, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
StringLists = ['1,8,0,9','4,5,2,2','4,6,7,2','4,2,8,9']
print map(lambda s: map(int, s.split(',')), StringLists)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 8, 0, 9], [4, 5, 2, 2], [4, 6, 7, 2], [4, 2, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
TempList = [map(int, d.split(',')) for d in StringLists]
```